# Which is ideal road-bike size for a person with height 5'9.5"?

Tags: road-bike, frames

I am 5'9.5" and in seam length between legs is 33 inch. What is the optimium frame size?

Comment: Totally depends on your preference and what you're planning on using it for. Do you have a specific usage (touring, racing, etc) in mind?

Comment: A better question might be "What are the advantages/disadvantages of buying a larger or smaller fitting frame for my size"

Comment: 2 cm, in the grand scheme of things, is far less important than over all fit and suitability of the bike.

Comment: Please use the search function: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=frame+size

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ten thousand expert opinions can't match a single objective test. I'm about your same height and inseam. I have 52cm, 54cm, 56cm, and even a 51. They all fit, and work for me. One manufacture's 54 will sometimes feel like another manufacturer's 56cm. Fit isn't just about frame size. Stem, saddle position, spacer count, all play into it. Ya gotta test ride a couple of different makes and sizes. If you're like me, you're gonna want to write your findings down on paper to review once the "wow, that was cool" factor wears off a bit.

Comment: I'm 5'11" and my road bike is a 58cm. Especially with older bikes versus newer bikes, when sizing wasn't as proportionally done as it is now, the number's meaning is more or less just something you put on the order form.

Answer (score 1):

Go ride the bike.

For some people of the same height+inseam, the 54 may be better. Others may find the 56 better. Others may find both of them are bad for them. And if you switch the model of bike, you may find the results reverse, despite the same frame size.